# I need advice on parsing a large text file (6GB in size)

Tags: database, parsing, file, text

I need advice on parsing a large text file - 6GB in size

What I have done is download all my Gmail using Thundervird
I now have an mbox file with all my email in - this is a text file - of size 6GB

I need to parse this file and pull out specific data that follows a specific pattern

**First question**: what language should I use?
I've searched some other threads similar to this and understand that Perl or Python (and one or 2 others) would be fine

**Second question though**: I read in one of the post replies that it might be better to load the text file into a database and let the database search through the text file?

I need to have a CSV generated as an output

So... is it wiser for me to go the DB route?

**Third question**: How long is a piece of string... erm I mean... how long will it take to go through my 6Gb file... OK, not possible to answer without some details!

I need to pull out the following data:

```
First Name: 
Last Name: 

Address:

Telephone: 
Mobile:
Email:
```

So... I need to know if I need to run the script and leave my machine running overnight
I'm not sure if the above is a really dumb question or not - but I thought I'd ask anyway

ANY replies would be great

Thanks

Omar

Comment: at 50MB/sec you should be able to parse your data in about 20 minutes.

Comment: i got someone to write me a perl script - 20 minutes seems to be spot on, that's how long it takes to go through the whole file

Comment: yep thats pretty much the HD speed nowadays, happy you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use whatever language you're more familiar with. In terms of performance, Perl programs generally can parse text data faster than python.
2. You need to parse the data regardless of using database or not. If you're going to be doing a lot of queries/searches afterwards, then you should consider loading the parsed data into a database.
3. Depends on how complex the pattern you're trying to match on. Probably no more than 1 hour.

Comment: that *really* helps. thanks. i got someone to write me a perl script in the end. that does the job very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aperture project to query the mbox contents:

http://aperture.sourceforge.net/